# Wire size issue

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am running a circuit for electric car charging from my house underground through schedule 80 pvc conuduit to my unattached garage.  It’s a 240 volt 50 amp circuit so I must use # 6 AWG.  But since this load is almost entirely balanced must the neutral and the ground be the same size or can I use smaller wires for those conductors?

Comment: What to the instructions for  the charger say?

Comment: If it was entirely balanced, not almost, just a 240V charger and nothing else, it wouldn't need a neutral at all.  If it uses the neutral for anything, since it doesn't have its own breaker the wire has to be suitable for the only breaker protecting it, 50A.

Comment: @jay613 that's the answer, why not post it...

Answer (score 2):

### A few points

First, EVs don't use neutral.  The J1772 connector doesn't even have a neutral pin... and there's not much inside an EVSE, so it doesn't need neutral (unless they *really* chintzed out on the internal GFCI, in which case, **don't buy that one**). So neutral wire goes away.

[image]

Second, you may be able to run better wire insulation that allows higher temperature  -- 75C thermal instead of your assumption of 60C.  This in turn allows higher ampacity -- allowing **8 AWG copper wire to carry 50A**. Or #6 aluminum, *if* you can terminate the aluminum wire on a lug rated for aluminum.

Almost every wire can run 75C thermal.  The wires that CAN'T are:

- NM type cables, but those aren't allowed outdoors anyway.
- UF type cables, but FYI, 6/3 UF requires a 2" conduit, and 6/2 UF requires a 1-1/2" conduit.  Not a fan of cables in conduits.
- TW type individual wires, very obsolete.

So I would advise not using those types.

In the parts of the circuit which are in conduit, you can use THHN individual wires.  Those are readily available and are good for 75C. (90C actually, though that doesn't buy you anything).

For ground sizes, you have to look at the wire.  If the wire's legal maximum ampacity is <=60A, you use a #10 ground wire.  If it is <=100A, you use #8.

So for instance, 6 AWG copper THHN wire is good to 65A. That will necessitate a #8 Cu ground because the wire is good to 65A. The fact that  you're only using 50A is irrelevant.

Aluminum ground is legal at -2 numerical wire sizes larger, *if insulated*.  No bare aluminum grounds outdoors.

"In conduit" is outdoors.  All outdoor conduits are presumed to be 100% full of water 100% of the time.

### What I would do, easy version

I would run #6 *aluminum wire* as far as possible.  If the EVSE's terminals are rated for aluminum, that's great.  Otherwise, I would use ILSCO's "Mac Block Connector" to pigtail #6 aluminum to #8 THHN copper at the EVSE.

### What I would do, hard version

My guess is, this isn't your last EV, and/or, you'll want to power other stuff out at the garage.

As such, I would grab commodity aluminum #2 wire (e.g. 2-2-2-4 MH feeder).  It is a popular size due to being legal for 100A whole-house services.  Since it's not a whole house, we only get 90A, but that's fine.

I would run that to a subpanel. Spaces are laughably cheap and there's no excuse for running out of spaces, so I would get a 24-space, probably 200A rated, with a main breaker with a trip rating of "I don't care".

2 of those spaces would feed a 50A breaker to power the EVSE.  The others would be used for whatever.

That will leave you well-positioned to support 80A EVSE's in the future, as well as whatever wood shop or machine shop you please to develop.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes you could reduce the size of the neutral conductor. It is probably only used to supply 120v to the computer power supply. Why it couldn't be derived from the 240v source? Your guess is as good as mine.

The problem with doing this is, if you're installing a plug, like a NEMA 14-50, there is no control of what kind of device could be plugged into it in the future. So there would be a risk of overloading that conductor in the future. The NEC does not allow exceptions for transient conditions and take into account that a home will be sold and occupied by a non electrician in the future.

Also, there are no specific provisions in the Code for derating the neutral for an EV charger. There are provisions for doing so with services, feeders and electric ranges and dryers, but not EV chargers specifically. The Code Making Panel is constantly trying to keep up with insanely fast growing technology but has been falling behind very rapidly.

So, in short, my advice to you is to install a full size neutral conductor.

Now if cost us your concern, I have some advice to offer you that may help you save money and also give you the capacity for future circuit additions to your garage.

Most EV chargers call for copper wiring for it's supply and be even be a condition of warranty. The way around that is you run a 100 amp feeder in aluminum XHHW to a sub panel (#1 AWG). This over sized feeder will also help with any voltage drop considerations. Then you can put your EV plug right next to the panel and use far less copper.

The truth is that we electricians are using aluminum everywhere now for feeders and services. Even for electric ranges and dryers we are using aluminum SER cable. There's absolutely nothing wrong with it if it's installed properly and on lugs rated for it (which is just about all of them). The aluminum scare of the 80s and 90s was due to aluminum NM cable the used which was really just too small to be used in the manner it was.